# Javascript and Rails number validation

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Update:**

**When printing out the numbers, they are actually exactly the same, and both only show two decimal places. Also, in my database, these values are of type decimal with precision 8 and scale 2**

I have a pieces model in my rails app. This pieces model has two fields: artist_cut and total_price. In the edit form of the piece, I have some javascript that calculates the total_price of the piece based on the artist_cut. I have used a readonly field for the artist_cut to prevent users from editing that field.

However, readonly fields can be easily foiled, and so I added a validation to make sure that the total_price of the piece was the value I want. If not, then it throws an error.

The validation works with all artist_cuts except those that are between 3892 and 3898. In these cases, it thinks that the value produced by the javascript and the value produced by the ruby are not equal, which does not make sense to me. How can I fix this?

_form.html.erb

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :artist_cut %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :artist_cut, class: "form-control", id: "artist_cut" %>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :total_price %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :total_price, class: "form-control", id: "total_price", readonly: true %>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on("change", "#artist_cut", function() {
      var artist_cut = $("#artist_cut").val() || 0;
      $("#total_price").val(Math.ceil((((artist_cut*2.19)+0.3)/(1-0.029))*100)/100);
    });
</script>
```

piece.rb

```
validates :artist_cut, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, numericality: { greater_than: 0.5, less_than: 443378.86 }
validates :total_price, presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, numericality: true
validate :total_price_validation


def total_price_validation
  return if self.total_price == ((((self.artist_cut*2.19)+0.3)/(1-0.029))*100).ceil/100.0
  errors.add(:total_price, "cannot be changed")
end
```

Thanks

Comment: One this to be aware of is that you are doing floating-point comparisons. Because computers can only accurately represent rational numbers whose denominator is a power of 2, you will get small rounding errors. You should instead check whether the absolute value of the difference between expected and true value is correct.

Comment: @csander How would I check this absolute value difference?

Comment: @csander Wait I understand what you are saying. In the validation, I checked that the absolute value of the difference of the total price minus the value of the formula was less than or equal to 0.0000000001. This worked beautifully. If you put this as an answer, I can mark it as correct :)

Comment: I posted the response as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to be aware of is that you are doing floating-point comparisons. Because computers can only accurately represent rational numbers whose denominator is a power of 2, you will get small rounding errors. You should instead check whether the absolute value of the difference between expected and true value is very small.

Comment: The code implementation for this was   `return if (self.total_price - ((((self.artist_cut*2.19)+0.3)/(1-0.029))*100).ceil/100.0).abs <= 0.0000000001`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try rounding both to two decimal places? That might fix the small different in floating point calculation, as mentioned by csander.

```
Math.round(Math.ceil((((artist_cut*2.19)+0.3)/(1-0.029))*100)/100, 2)


(((((self.artist_cut*2.19)+0.3)/(1-0.029))*100).ceil/100.0).round(2)
```

Comment: I did this, but it did not work. Don't the .ceil methods serve to round them anyway?

Comment: Also, this seems to make the javascript round to the nearest whole number

Answer (score 0):

As noted by other, the problem is that floating point comparisons are not suitable for your needs. The solution is to change the the `artist_cut` column to a Decimal type (check the docs for whichever database you are using) and replace the float values in your code to [BigDecimal](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html).

```
def total_price_validation
  return if self.total_price == ((((self.artist_cut * "2.19".to_d)+"0.3".to_d)/(1 - "0.029".to_d)) * 100).ceil / 100
```

Comment: The artist_cut was always a decimal type. I tried the to_d method that you specified, but got the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: This actually doesn't make it work even for the other cases where it was working before.